# why cannot I create tables on postresql?

Tags: postgresql

was doing school practice, when copy teachers command from slide,
[image: right table creation picture]

create table no problem, but when I try to create another table any handwriting the command in SQL Command, display some error

[image: table creation with error].

Do you know why, how I can fix it?

this is what it looks like after adding data types for colums[added data types

```
CREATE TABLE project (
id,
name varchar(64),
employee_id int
)
```

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: You are missing the data type for each column in your second statement.

Comment: okay, tried to add data types, still not working, thank you for your help

Comment: Your `id` field is still missing a datatype. You can use  `serial` like your teacher which is a special datatype having build in sequence. Or just integer if you will. But some datatype have to be declared there as wel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.